# MYSQL MAX/COUNT/IN/DATE

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hope you can advise. Im pulling my hair out on a query and hope you can advise.

I have a table where I want to select MAX from an inner count between dates with an IN.

[View Table](http://www.screencast.com/users/openeye/folders/Jing/media/0b162b34-4f06-463d-a270-533a85858d28)

Here is what I have tried but with no luck at all.

```
SELECT MAX(no_hits) from (SELECT count(hits) AS 'no_hits' ) FROM stats WHERE 'date' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND zones_code IN('011242077793513596890', '011242077783866125432'))
```

So basically I only want one no_hits returned for the best performing zone.

Hope you can advise on where im going wrong.

And thank you if you cam

Comment: Could you post the definition of your stats table, some example data, and an example result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is this:

```
SELECT MAX(no_hits) 
FROM (SELECT count(hits) AS 'no_hits' ) FROM stats 
  WHERE 'date' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
    AND zones_code IN('011242077793513596890', '011242077783866125432')
);
```

Here are some things wrong with your query:

- You closed the subquery parentheses after `'no_hits'`.
- You didn't supply a table alias for the subquery.  Every derived table must have a table alias.
- You didn't close the parentheses for the `DATE_SUB()` function.
- You used `COUNT()` where I think you should use `SUM()`, if you want the total of hits per zone.
- You aren't associating the subtotal of hits with each zone; your subtotal is for the whole table.
- You used string delimiters (`''`) for `'date'` instead of identifier delimiters (i.e. back-quotes).  You're comparing the literal string `'date'` to a date value, when you mean to compare the column `date` to a date value.

The query in @chaos's answer is close, but I think you should use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT `zones_code`, SUM(`hits`) AS `no_hits`
FROM `stats`
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY `zones_code`
ORDER BY `no_hits` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The result is zone_code 011242077793513596890, with a total of 255 hits.

---

PS:  When you ask questions online, please supply *in textual format* enough code and data for people to test easily.  You supplied a screenshot of some sample data, and without showing the table creation code.  This is not as helpful as if you had supplied a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement and a sample `INSERT` statement to populate it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zones_code` char(21) default NULL,
  `date` date default NULL,
  `hits` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO stats VALUES
(10, '011242077793513596890', '2009-05-11', 13),
(12, '011242077793513596890', '2009-05-12',235),
(24, '011242077793513596890', '2009-05-13',  2),
(32, '011242077793513596890', '2009-05-14',  5),
(17, '011242077783866125432', '2009-05-12',165),
(22, '011242077783866125432', '2009-05-13',  2),
(30, '011242077783866125432', '2009-05-14',  5),
(19, '011242077743853330663', '2009-05-12', 61),
(20, '011242077737314753388', '2009-05-12', 54),
(28, '011242077737314753388', '2009-05-13',  7),
(36, '011242077737314753388', '2009-05-14', 31),
(14, '011242077730456603312', '2009-05-12',240),
(26, '011242077730456603312', '2009-05-13',  2),
(34, '011242077730456603312', '2009-05-14',  5);
```

The above is what I had to type in based on your screen shot!

*Do yourself a favor and make it easier for people to help you.*

Comment: Fair comment made.

I will post more data next time. I did think after previous post the SUM should have been used to add them togther.

Thanks again all.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `zones_code`, SUM(`hits`) AS `no_hits`
FROM `stats`
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY `zones_code`
ORDER BY `no_hits` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Its close but not correct.  The result im getting is.

13131313131313131313

?

Comment: I do not understand how you could possibly be getting that.  You're probably going to have to give us more code context before it's clear what's going on.  What happens when you run the query above directly in mysql client or phpmyadmin?

Comment: @chaos: The result of your query in my test is "4".  I don't know what Lee is talking about.

Comment: Yeah, something wacky's going on there.  4 isn't quite right, though.  (Because I had COUNT not SUM.  What I get for copying and pasting OP's query...)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `ORDER BY DESC` ordering clause with a `LIMIT 1` to get only the maximum value.

Comment: This WILL give you the maximum value.  By sorting from largest to smallest, and taking only the first, you are getting the top result; since you only have a single column in your query, this will result in a scalar.

Comment: Even when I remove the LIMIT 1 I still get same result ?

Comment: I can't debug your code for you (particularly without your table structure and data); this is intended as information to allow you to guide your research and find the solution, not debugging your problems.